# how to retrieve the table names from oracle database which was created recently using oracle sql

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to retrieve all the table names which were created 1 hour back.

I have written the below query,

```
select table_name from user_tables where table_name created >= (sysdate-1/24);
```

But the above query is not displaying any value.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not correct. BTW, You can use USER_OBJECTS instead -

```
select object_name from user_objects where created >= (sysdate-1/24);
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e5e448200c39485dd018289303ca6b96)